# Cannot open ADF file in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am having opening the adf files from [this ftp server](ftp://lidar.engr.oregonstate.edu/OREGON%20LIDAR%20CONSORTIUM%20PROJECT%20DATA/OLC%20WILLAMETTE%20VALLEY%202009/RASTERS/HIGHEST_HIT/)  in QGIS. I can open the .ovr files, but they end up in the middle of the ocean.

Comment: ".adf" files are but one component of an Esri ArcInfo GRID or coverage dataset.  Did you download the *entire* "HIGHEST_HIT" directory, including the "info" subdirectory?

Comment: I tried loading the individual .adf files straight from the ftp, without first downloading. I am trying to avoid downloading the full 50+ gb directory at once, due to limited storage. Is there any way to download something like this in pieces?

Answer (score 2):

Your "ADF" files are actually Esri [ArcInfo Binary GRID](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/arcinfo_grid_format.html) format.

You can't just download the .adf files, you need the whole folder (and the info folder if you want to use the data in Esri ArcGIS products but will work without it in QGIS).

[image]

However, GDAL has a ["/vsicurl/" virtual file system](https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html) which can handle figuring out which files to access remotely without downloading the entire dataset.

I could not get QGIS to load the Esri GRIDs directly using "/vsicurl/", but I could download and convert to GeoTIFF using "/vsicurl/" with `gdal_translate`.

This worked for me:

```
gdal_translate /vsicurl/ftp://lidar.engr.oregonstate.edu/OREGON%20LIDAR%20CONSORTIUM%20PROJECT%20DATA/OLC%20WILLAMETTE%20VALLEY%202009/RASTERS/HIGHEST_HIT/hh45123e2b/hdr.adf hh45123e2b.tif
```

[image]